# RIng with Coercion url parameter returning :status 500

Tags: clojure, ring, reitit

This is my app:

```
(def routes
  [["/api"
    ping-routes
    submissions-routes]])

(def app
  (ring/ring-handler
    (ring/router routes
      {:data {:coercion reitit.coercion.schema/coercion
              :muuntaja m/instance
              :middleware [[wrap-cors
                            :access-control-allow-origin [#"http://localhost:4200"]
                            :access-control-allow-methods [:get :post]]
                           parameters-middleware
                           format-negotiate-middleware
                           format-response-middleware
                           exception-middleware
                           format-request-middleware
                           coerce-exceptions-middleware
                           coerce-request-middleware
                           coerce-response-middleware]}})
    (ring/routes
      (ring/redirect-trailing-slash-handler {:method :strip})
      (ring/create-default-handler
       {:not-found (constantly {:status 404 :body "Route not found"})}))))

(def ping-routes
  ["/ping" {:get (fn [req]
                   {:status 200
                    :body {:ping "pong"}})}])


(def submissions-routes
  ["/submissions"
   ["" {:get get-submissions}]
   ["/:id" {:get {:parameters {:path {:id s/Int}}
                      :handler get-submission-by-id}}]])


(comment 
  (get-submission-by-id {:parameters {:path 20}}))
```

When I try access "submissions/1 I get "{"type":"exception","class":"clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo"}" in the browser or within the repl:

```
{:status 500,
 :body
 #object[java.io.ByteArrayInputStream 0x3db2e139 "java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@3db2e139"],
 :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json; charset=utf-8"}}
```

If I run my comment code then the get-submission-by-id handler works fine on it's own. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define your routes more precisely with names and strict structuring, like this:

```
(def submissions-routes
      [["/submissions" {:name ::experiment}
        ["" {:name ::root-submission-route
             :get  {:handler (fn [_] {:status 200
                                      :body   {:resp "empty get"}})}}]
        ["/:id" {:name ::root-submission-route-id
                 :get  {:parameters {:path {:id Long}}
                        :handler    (fn [r] {:status 200 :body {:resp (-> r :path-params :id)}})}}]]])
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a bunch turns out I wasn't getting the parameters out of the arguments correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* (and this is partially due to you not providing a proper
MVCE), that you are mixing up the name spaces for Schema (`schema.core`)
and the schema coercion from reitit (`reitit.ring.coercion`).

If you require:

- `reitit.coercion.schema :as rcs`
- `schema.core :as s`

And use `:coercion rcs/coercion` in your router, this problem should be
solved.

Next, you should never have to *guess* what the problem is.  Make sure,
that you know, what exceptions are thrown.  E.g. you can print
exceptions, if you replace `exception-middleware` with

```clj
(rrme/create-exception-middleware
 (merge
  rrme/default-handlers
  {::rrme/wrap (fn [handler ex req]
          (prn ex)
          (handler ex req))}))
```

with `reitit.ring.middleware.exception :as rrme` in your requires.

Answer (score 0):

**s/Int** to be replaced by **Long**
By default numbers in Java are longs.

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).